# Rewrite Preview URL to include index.php

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

Our WordPress website has a static html home page. A request for the domain returns the `index.html` page.

This has served our purposes well, but has caused a problem when trying to preview a post or page during editing. Since the preview URLs do not include `index.php` all preview requests display the static home page; e.g.,

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=7848&preview=true
```

OR

```
http://www.example.com/?post_type=solution&p=6480&preview_id=6480&preview_nonce=730eb2844c&preview=true
```

Both display the home page. Manually inserting `index.php` between `www.example.com/` and `?<querystring>` works and display the page preview, but it is a pain.

I have tried the following in `functions.php`, which does update the `.htaccess` file, but the home page still appears.

```
function custom_rewrite_preview( )
{
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.*)\?(.+)&preview=true$',
    '$1index.php?$2&preview=false',
    'bottom'
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_preview' );
```

I am unsure whether the function and/or regex are wrong, or that the rewrite needs to occur at a different time.

Comment: try this filter : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/preview_post_link/

Comment: hi, thanks so much! the filter you referenced got me on right track. 

`function nst_update_post_link($link) {
  $host = parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_HOST );
  $link = preg_replace("/$host\/\?/", "$host/index.php?", $link);
  return $link;
}
add_filter('preview_post_link', 'nst_update_post_link');

function nst_update_page_link($link) {
  $host = parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_HOST );
  $link = preg_replace("/$host\/\?/", "$host/index.php?", $link);
  return $link;
}
add_filter('preview_page_link', 'nst_update_page_link');`

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your rewrites. Put the content of the HTML file into a front-page.php template file in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rewrite rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^taxo=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Clear your browser's cache and any domain that follows this structure:

```
http://www.example.com/?page_id=7848&preview=true
```

Will redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page_id=7848&preview=true
```

This has been verified and tested on my end using the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).